# Align LaTeX formula to text in Manim

Tags: python, text, latex, manim

I use the Poppins font for text and LaTeX for formulas (picture: number 1). The LaTeX text is vertically aligned higher than the Poppins text. I want both texts to be aligned on a horizontal line, like in (Image: number 2). How can I do that?

I use the function `next_to()` so that I can use the Poppins text and the LaTeX formula as continuous text. Is there perhaps a better way of creating continuous text using Poppins text and LaTeX formulas alternately?

[Two types of text representation. Once with Poppins and LaTeX and once with LaTex only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tJdb.png)
`

```
class ProofPowerSeries(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        definitionbn = Text("Sei", font="Poppins", color=BLACK, line_spacing=3).scale(0.5).to_edge(UL)
        reason = MathTex(r"b_n := a_n(z-z_0)", color=BLACK).scale(0.75)
        reason.next_to(definitionbn, buff=0.1)
        latex = Tex("Sei $b_n := a_n(z-z_0)$", color=BLACK)

        self.add(definitionbn, reason, latex)
```

`

I use the `Text()` function for text and `MathTex()`  for formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX-Schrift font aligns better if you use `align_edge=UP`  in the `next_to()` function.

```
reason.next_to(definitionbn, aligned_edge=UP, buff=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use common .ttf-fonts with modern LaTeX, also in Manim. See my answer to your other question, `xetex` should be part of every modern LaTeX installation.

```
class ZWSAufgabe(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        Tex.set_default(color=BLACK)
        self.camera.background_color = WHITE
        myTexTemplate = TexTemplate(
            tex_compiler="xelatex",
            output_format='.xdv',
        )
        myTexTemplate.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Poppins}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}")
        
        aufgabe = Tex(
            r'''Zeige, dass die Funktion $f(x) := sin(x) - e^{-x}$\\ 
            im Intervall $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ genau eine Nullstelle 
            besitzt.''',
            tex_template=myTexTemplate,
            tex_environment="flushleft"
        ).to_edge(UL)
        aufgabe.scale(0.75)
        self.play(Write(aufgabe))
```

[image: rendered output]